# Spotlight effect in actionscript-flash

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, spotlight

Can anyone point me to a good demo or tutorial on creating a hollywood style spotlight effect?

2 soft edged rays pointing down towards a 'floor' and criss crossing each other

Answer (score 0):

Hope these links helps you:

http://snipplr.com/view/25032/
http://www.pixeldigest.com/spotlight_effect.html
http://declic-video-fx.com/language/en-US/Tutorials/ID/569/Graffiti-Spotlight-effect.aspx
http://workflowflash.com/615/3d-moving-spotlight-and-shadow-effect-in-as3-and-flash.php
http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/mask_as_bc/
http://abduzeedo.com/awesome-background-light-effects-flash-3-flasheff-component-giveaway
http://www.3dnewmedia.com/v1.0/index.htm